# Do you know a good program to draw DVCS graphs?

Tags: graph, dvcs

Recently I was trying to introduce improvements to a DVCS workflow in the company I work for. To make it happen I need to write a document describing the changes - cause it's for managers - the more pictures / graphs the better.

Do you know any program (for Windows preferably) in which it's easy to draw graphs representing branches, commits and merges? I've tried Visio but it's not exactly what I expected (or maybe I just need new stencils).

EDIT: The result I would like to accomplish is similar to this one: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ The author didn't answer to the questions about the software used in the comment's though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this online tool http://www.lucidchart.com, although it is not the same one.

Answer (score 0):

I can recomment [yEd from yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html).  It is free and can produce some beautiful graphs for a fairly wide array of use cases.  It does have some relatively minor foibles, but it gets the job done more than it gets in my way.